# matchMedia doesnt work unless window is resized

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, addeventlistener, matchmedia

I'm trying to use the window.matchMedia event listener to detect if the user is on a touch device or not. But im just seems to be only activate when the chrome DevTools window is resized, and not actually detect if it is a touch device (for example, on my pixel 3a).

here is the code i used for the event listener

```
if (matchMedia) {
        let mql = window.matchMedia('(pointer: fine)');
        mql.addListener(touchChange)
    }
```

and the function which it runs

```
function touchChange (event) {
if (event.matches) {
    touchcontrols = true;
    console.log("Touch Controls");
    console.log(window.innerWidth);
    document.getElementById("lives").innerHTML = "Touch Events!";
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to see if it matches once you can use:

```
let matches = window.matchMedia('(pointer: fine)').matches;
```

`window.matchMedia` returns an object with a `matches` property which indicates if it's currently matching your query and an `addListener` to register a callback which will be called in response to the media query status changing.

More on this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaQueryList/addListener

Comment: do you mind expanding on your answer or providing a link? i don't completely understand sorry.